# Query Producing Wrong Results

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, query, arcgis-10.5

I'm doing a simple query on a points feature class that has a table joined to it. I'm querying for values equal to 0 and my results are incorrect.

[image]

No coded domains, this is on ArcMap 10.5. Any explanation for this? Only caught it because I happened to check, but this would be terrible for any analysis.

Comment: Hope this doesn't sound dumb to you, but you can double-check that 1) you are looking at the right field? You seem to be working with the shapefiles and they have a limitation for 10 characters for the field 2) It's an integer field 3) Can you test running similar simple queries on other fields before join and after join, joining them and other fields?

Answer (score 1):

One explanation is that the field is actually a text field, which is very likely when using a table join.

Try changing the select query to "YourField" = '0' or ensure that the source table column is formatted as a number field and not text.